# Align content within center of cell but keep left alignment of text

Tags: html

I am looking for some html help. How would I go about moving a text block centrally within a cell but also keeping their alignment left intact. I do not wish the text to be displayed all centered as I am going to be using an unordered list. I simply want the block of text to be moved in to the center of the cell.

Example of current scenario:
http://jsfiddle.net/AygnN/

Comment: What do you want centered? The `h1`, the `ul`, *everything*?

Comment: I would like the ul blocks to be in the middle of the cells with a left align of their text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table id="sub-content" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Departments</th>
      <th>KPI Types</th>
      <th>Bonus</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>dfgsdgfdfg</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>sdfgsdfgsdfg</li>  
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>sdgsdfgsdffgsdgf</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have the `<h1>` tags as column headers, you should use actual table headers (`<th>` tags). Now, in the CSS you can say:

```
th { text-align:center; }
```

**EDIT:**

```
#sub-content td{ padding:0px 60px; }
```

and all table headers will be centered while all lists in the table will be aligned to the left.

This method is much more standard.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NTc2v/1/)

Comment: I'm actually looking to have the ul content centred within the td cell but also keeping its left alignment intact. At the moment the ul elements align to the left but they all sit on the left hand side of the cells making the page look skewed to the side. I can centre the ul elements but the they lose their left align blockyness

Comment: Lol. You don't want alignment, you want padding. If the bullets of the list are aligned on the left, then what determines center? Updated post to do padding, and added a Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text in a div and host the div inside the table cell. The text will follow the css style specified in div where as the div itself will be in center of the cell.

The example you have given does same kind of things. It rather divides the cell in multiple cells and put the text in the middle one.